# Exporting random forest decision tree (or thresholds) Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

Is there any way to export/view the generated decision tree from a random forest classifier in Google Earth Engine?

I know that

```
classifier.explain()
```

works for a CART classifier. Anything similar for

```
ee.Classifier.randomForest()
```

Alternatively, is there any way to export/view the thresholds used in the random forest decision tree?

Comment: This is not how random forests works. It is an ensemble learner and estimates are based on the plurality of votes across all tree nodes for the entire ensemble. There are no rules and any given single tree in the ensemble is meaningless.